# WebGoBack command in Word started opening a new read-only version of the document

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, read-only

In Office 365, Word, I use the WebGoBack command (alt+left arrow) a lot. Today, for no reason I can fathom, when I use this command, it opens a new, read-only version of the document I'm working in and takes me back to the previous position in that document, rather than the one I'm working in. Has anyone had this problem before or know what could be causing it?

Comment: Does this happen if you [start Word in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7)?